# Perl: Load data by row

Tags: arrays, perl, file, hash

I'm continuing my Perl learning.

In this case I'm trying to load data from .txt file into array. My script generates `netstat` output which looks like this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address    Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp     0      0 0.0.0.0:3790        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7550/nginx.conf 
tcp     0      0 127.0.1.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1271/dnsmasq    
tcp     0      0 127.0.0.1:631       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24202/cupsd
```

Next step in process is to put data which is loaded from file into array and then in hash, making it sortable by rows, for example sorting output to find out all information which belongs specific port number.

My question is: What is proper way to load this data into array and then hash to make it accessible and sortable for the output?

Comment: In order to load it into a hash you need to decide on a key.  In this case, that amounts to "What do you want to sort on?"

Comment: @Degustaf almost everything except `Recv-Q` and `Send-Q`. It includes  `PID` and `Program name` which are separated by `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need AoH (array of hashes). After that you can get everything you want with custom `sort`:

```
my @records = [
 { Proto => "tcp", 'Recv-Q' => 0, ..., 'Local Address' => "0.0.0.0:3790", ..., State => "Listen", ... },
 { Proto => "tcp", 'Recv-Q' => 0, ..., 'Local Address' => "127.0.1.1:53", ..., State => "Listen", ... },
 { Proto => "tcp", 'Recv-Q' => 0, ..., 'Local Address' => "127.0.0.1:631", ..., State => "Listen", ... },
];

my @records_sorted_by_state = sort { $a->{State} cmp $b->{State} } @records;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @gangabass! AoH is what I was looking for,  **but** your solution means that all data must be written manually into the script, I'm looking for solution where data can be imported with by script.

Comment: Sorry but I don't want write code for you. Try to parse your data yourself and ask for help after that.

Comment: Spasibo i na etom. +1